# How to switch between AndroidElement and WebElement?

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

I m working on Mobile Web Application Automation. Here I m using Java, Selenium and Appium. There are two fields which I m not able to automate. They are Date and drop down fields. I can able automate text fields, check boxes and radio buttons. When clicking on Date Field, there comes the Android default date picker, in which I cant able to pick a date. Here is my code below:

```
class openBrowser() {   
public static WebDriver driver;   
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> androidDriver;   
@Test   
public static void launchBrowser(){   
desiredCapabalities(...);   
androidDriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new 
URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desiredCapabilities));    
driver = androidDriver;   
}

class pickDate() {    
MobileElement element;
try{    
element = (MobileElement) 
androidDriver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='28 May  
2017']").click();   
}catch(Exception e) { 
throw e; 
}  
}
```

"findElementByXPath()" looks only for the web element, but not searching for Android/Mobile element. Please refer date picker screenshot: [Date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtSOM.jpg)

Kindly suggest me any solution to switch between Web Element and Android/Mobile Element. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace?

Comment: Since, I got solved, dint take the stack trace. But it states, 'NoSuchElementException' along with driver details and capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution from the below link:
[switch contexts i.e Native App and Web View](https://community.perfectomobile.com/posts/944337-using-context-in-selenium-tests)

```
public static void switchToContext(String context) throws Exception {
    try {
        RemoteExecuteMethod executeMethod = new RemoteExecuteMethod((RemoteWebDriver) androidDriver);
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", context);
        executeMethod.execute(DriverCommand.SWITCH_TO_CONTEXT, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static String getCurrentContextHandle() throws Exception{
    try{
        RemoteExecuteMethod executeMethod = new RemoteExecuteMethod((RemoteWebDriver) androidDriver);
        String context =  (String) executeMethod.execute(DriverCommand.GET_CURRENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE, null);
        return context;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public static List<String> getContextHandles() throws Exception{          
    try {
        RemoteExecuteMethod executeMethod = new RemoteExecuteMethod((RemoteWebDriver) androidDriver);
        List<String> contexts =  (List<String>) executeMethod.execute(DriverCommand.GET_CONTEXT_HANDLES, null);
        return contexts;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the link you provided is dead